# Chrome hides video after .pause() and .currentTime=0 call

Tags: javascript, html, video, media

Is it only me having the issue with Chrome hiding video after I call .pause() and .currentTime = 0 via JavaScript?
The source goes like this:

```
<video class="js-video" preload="auto" muted playsinline>
  <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<script>
  var video = document.querySelector('.js-video');
  let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    if (entries[0].intersectionRatio > 0.8 && entries[0].isIntersecting) {
      video.play();
    } else {
      video.pause();
      video.currentTime = 0;
    }
  }, {
    threshold: 0.8
  });
  observer.observe(video.parentNode);
</script>
```

When I open that page in Firefox, video plays when in viewport and pauses/restarts when out of viewport by more than 80%. All is good. But when I open the same page in Google, video is hidden after it goes out of viewport. It shows up again when I scroll into it, but hides again when I scroll out.

Comment: " It shows up again when I scroll into it, but hides again when I scroll out." -- isn't that your expected behavior?

Comment: No, expected behavior is pausing the video and rewinding to sec 0.